# How to get data from custom component?

Tags: admin-on-rest, react-admin

I have an edit action inside my model file. I am using default react-admin components, unfortunately I had to created my custom component and after the form is submitted no data from this custom component were provided.

I have tried to wrap the whole component inside `<FormControl>` , it does not do the trick for me.

My component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import { fetchUtils } from 'react-admin';

const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    formControl: {
      margin: theme.spacing.unit,
      minWidth: 120,
      maxWidth: 300,
    },
    chips: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    chip: {
      margin: theme.spacing.unit / 4,
    },
    noLabel: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    },
  });

  const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
  const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
  const MenuProps = {
    PaperProps: {
      style: {
        maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
        width: 250,
      },
    },
  };

  function getStyles(name, that) {
    return {
      fontWeight:
        that.state.name.indexOf(name) === -1
          ? that.props.theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
          : that.props.theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
    };
  }

var names = [];

class MultipleSelect extends React.Component {
    state = {
        name: [
        ]
    };

    getRoles() {
        const url = 'URLTOENDPOINT'
        var data = [];
        fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, {
            method: "GET",
        })
        .then(response => {
            Object.keys(response.json.value).forEach(function (key) {
                var object = response.json.value[key];
                data.push({
                  name: object.Name,
                  value: object.Id
                });
            })
            this.setState({name: data});
        });
    }

    getAllOptions() {
      const url = 'URLTOENDPOINT'
      var data = [];
      fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, {
          method: "GET",
      })
      .then(response => {
          Object.keys(response.json.value).forEach(function (key) {
              var object = response.json.value[key];
              data.push({
                name: object.Name,
                value: object.Id
              });
          })
          names = data;
      });
  }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getRoles();
        this.getAllOptions();
        this.forceUpdate();
    }

    handleChange = event => {
      console.log("y",event);
      this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
    };

    render() {
      const { classes } = this.props;

      return (
        <div>
            <FormControl>
                <InputLabel htmlFor="UserRoles">Chip</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    multiple
                    value={this.state.name}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    input={<Input id="UserRoles" />}
                    renderValue={selected => (
                    <div className={classes.chips}>
                        {selected.map(obj => (
                          <Chip key={obj.value} label={obj.name} className={classes.chip} />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    )}
                    MenuProps={MenuProps}
                >
                    {names.map(obj => (
                      <MenuItem key={obj.value} value={obj.value} style={getStyles(obj.name, this)}>
                          {obj.name}
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  MultipleSelect.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(MultipleSelect);
```

EditAction:

```
export const UserEdit = props => (
  <Edit {...props} title={<UserTitle/>} aside={<Aside />}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <DisabledInput source="Id" />
      <TextInput source="Login" validate={required()} />
      <TextInput source="Email" type="email" validate={required()} />

      <ReferrenceSelectBox source="UserRoles" />

      <NullableBooleanInput source="Active" />
      <DateField source="CreatedDate" showTime
        locales={process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALE}
        disabled={true} />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

I need to show multiple select box with selected data from API, so i had wrote custom component, because default components did not help me, but it didnt change anything and also the data are not showing.

Comment: Can you post the full code of your custom component ? Have you decorated it with the `addField` higher order component as explained in the documentation ?

Comment: @GildasGarcia No i have not added `addField` yet. `addField` will put my component inside form?

Comment: Unless you included the Field component from redux-form yourself, yes, you have to decorate it with addField

Comment: @GildasGarcia After I added `addField` that i still could not get data in ODataProvider.js when i dumped `params`. There are all fields data, but not from my custom component. How does that `<ReferenceArrayInput>` works? When I created User I did not get data from that input too, but It handled the data itself i guess

Comment: Please setup a codesandbox with your component and the default dataProvider. It will ease debugging